# How I can fix this black hole I get when trying to do 2d lighting using normal maps?

Tags: c++, glsl

I have the following shader to draw lightning into 2D quads with normal maps

```
in vec2 position;
in vec2 texturePosition;

out vec4 fragColor;

layout(std140)  uniform ubo {
  mat4 uCameraView;
  vec3 uLightPosition;
};

uniform sampler2D uTexture0;
uniform sampler2D uTexture1;

// TODO: move into the ubo
const vec4 uLightColor = vec4(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
const vec4 uAmbientColor = vec4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
const vec3 uFalloff = vec3(0.1f, 3.f, 20.f);

void main() {
  vec4 difusseColor = texture(uTexture0, texturePosition);
  vec3 normalMap = texture(uTexture1, texturePosition).rgb;
  normalMap.y *= -1;

  vec3 lightDirection = vec3(uLightPosition.xy - position.xy, uLightPosition.z);
  float direction = length(lightDirection);
  vec3 light = normalize(lightDirection);
  vec3 normal = normalize(normalMap * 2.f - 1.f);

  vec3 diffuseLight = (uLightColor.rgb * uLightColor.a) * dot(normal, light);

  vec3 ambient = uAmbientColor.rgb * uAmbientColor.a;
  float attenuation = 1.f /
    (uFalloff.x + (uFalloff.y * direction) +
     (uFalloff.z * direction * direction));

  vec3 intensity = ambient + diffuseLight * attenuation;
  vec3 color = difusseColor.rgb * intensity;

  fragColor = vec4(color, difusseColor.a);
}
```

But the issue I get is this black hole behind the light

[image]

I can remove the black hole with this line of code

```
vec3 diffuseLight = (uLightColor.rgb * uLightColor.a) * max(dot(normal, light), 0.0f);
```

But then I get this misaligned light without illumination where the black hole was

[image]

This is my vertex shader

```
void main() {
  gl_Position = uCameraView * vec4(vPosition, 0.f, 1.f);
}
```

`uCameraView` is a mat4 perspective projection that is done like this

```
glm::vec3 camera;
glm::mat4 projection =
  glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.f), app.aspectRatio, 0.f, 100.f);
projection = glm::scale(projection, size.viewport.scale);
glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(projection, camera);
```

Is this possible to fix?

I tried following this tutorial https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson6 and in there the light look good.

Comment: You say you've been following this page but there seems to be differences between your code and theirs. Notably your falloff is based on the light direction, theirs seems to be a constant?

Comment: sorry, I updated the code to be the one from the tutorial. I tried a different one with the same result

Comment: `vec3 lightDirection = vec3(uLightPosition.xy - position.xy, uLightPosition.z);` Have you tried replacing this with just `uLightPosition - position`? It just struck me that this pretty much only works for a 2D game with camera aligned planes and from your screenshot you seem to be in 3D. (I'm assuming here that position and uLightPosition are already in the same 'space')

Comment: oh, this is a 2D game with isometric tiles. uLightPosition.z is required for the distance of the light from the plane

Comment: but are the tiles perpendicular to the camera? they might all be on the same plane but they look to be at an angle (where as the ones on github are all perpendicular to the camera)

Comment: @Borgleader I updated the question adding more info about my vertex shader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244942/discussion-between-ellipticaldoor-and-borgleader).

Comment: Don't set zero as the near plane in glm::perspective(). It will divide by zero when perspective division occurs, which is something you don't want. `vec3 ambient = uAmbientColor.rgb * uAmbientColor.a;` I think this is wrong. You're multiplying 0.2 by 0.2. And `dot(normal, light)` should probably be clamped. The tutorial takes the max: `max(dot(N, L), 0.0)`, making sure it's not a negative value.

Comment: @AndreiDespinoiu I changed the near plane from zero to 0.1f but nothing changed. Yeah, I also clamped the value but then it looks like in the second screenshot

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the normals, or the light dir. Try inspecting it with: `fragColor = vec4(normal, 1.0);`. And don't use `difusseColor.a` as the alpha of the final fragment, because if you load a JPG (format which doesn't have an alpha channel), it will be zero, causing all sorts of problems. You might be seeing the clear color behind it if it was set to black, or it might cause a transparency issue.